# How can I print multiple objects to console.log with dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

In javascript, if I have 3 variables like this:

```dart
var x = 1
var y = 'cat'
var z = {color: 'blue'}
```

I can log all of them like this:

```dart
console.log('The values are:', x, y, z)
```

In dart, you can `import 'dart:html'` and it will map `print` to `console.log` in the compiled javascript. But `print` only takes one parameter - not 3. This dart will fail when the compiled js runs in the browser:

```dart
print('The values are:', x, y, z)
```

The only thing I can think to do is stringify these arguments and join them into one string, and print that. But then I lose Chrome's ability to expand objects that are printed to the console.

Is it possible to print multiple objects with one `print` statement (or similar statement)? If so, how?

Comment: What happens if you do `print([x, y, z]);`?

Answer (score 13):

What about: ?

```dart
print('The values are: ${[x, y, z]}')
```

or

```dart
print('The values are: $x, $y, $z')
```

or

```dart
['The values are:', x, y, z].forEach(print);
```

Comment: Both versions print all objects as part of the string, instead of as independent objects. An actual javascript object (e.g. `{one: 1, ...}`) would not be expandable printed this way.

Comment: For each element `toString()` would be called and the result added to the string. I'm not a JavaScript programmer and not aware about how this might be handled differently there. I added yet another variant maybe this is more what you expect.

Comment: The third version prints all values, but prints objects as strings instead of objects. Maybe it is not possible.

Comment: It is what print does. It calls `toString()` on the passed values. Mybe you just want to use `window.console.debug` instead of `print` but produces only a different output in Dartiums console, not in the console view of DartEditor.

Comment: great answer!) @GünterZöchbauer, thanks again!) especially for the last one)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
print("$x,$y,$z");
```

or

```
stdout.write("$x,$y,$z");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, you can import [dart:html](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html) which gives you access to the `window.console`. Unfortunately, its log method can only take one argument. You can wrap your objects in a list though:

```
import 'dart:html';

var x = 1
var y = 'cat'
var z = {color: 'blue'}

window.console.log([x, y, z]);
```

Comment: Nice, but kind of sad that you have to do workarounds because dart doesn't match the browser api